# Where do I create custom UI elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

A quick question from a wanna-be iOS developer. I want to create a UI for an iPhone app without Interface Builder, only programmatically. However, I want to stick to MVC recommendations and separate V and C and have a clean readable code, therefore:

- I create UIView class files (e.x. SplashView.h and SplashView.m)
- I create UIViewController class files (SplashViewController.h and SplashViewController.m)
- I define my UI elements (view, subviews, buttons and text fields) in the UIView class files
- I load the main view in view controller's loadView method, and then do other things in view controller's viewDidLoad method

Is this a correct approach to begin with?

Second part of the question, independent of Y/N answer to the first. Where do I define these custom UI elements?
 - Inside the view's initWithFrame: method?
 - In separate (property getter? property setter?) methods? I.e. do I have to declare each UI element as a property first in the .h file?

If these questions sound a bit ignorant, it must be because they are :) I found lots of sample code on StackOverflow, but little to indicate where you actually put it. I would be really grateful for any help, especially if you could paste/reference some relevant code.

Comment: Why would you think about doing this outside of Xcode?  Licensing?  Cost?  Development environment? There is so much training material available for Xcode that you are making your job, as a beginner, all the more difficult.

Comment: @GoZoner Where is it stated that this is to be done outside of Xcode? The OP stated that they didn't want to use Interface Builder.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with constructing a UI programmatically instead of using IB in the same way that there's nothing particularly wrong with riding a bicycle everywhere instead of using a car. You'll get to your destination either way, but most people would say that the car is faster and less work. Do you have a particular reason to avoid IB, or does it just seem too mysterious? (I'm not criticizing those who go without IB, but you should definitely understand it before you decide against it, especially as a beginner.)

Comment: My main reason for not using IB is since all of my UI elements are custom, and I want to create them with resizable assets, then by having to select, say, UIButton of custom type, it becomes transparent/invisible in the IB. So if I can't see the interface I'm building, IB kind of loses purpose for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is correct. This is how I do all of my apps. No Interface Builder, just code.

Each custom view typically creates its own subviews in an appropriate `initXXX` method. This could be `initWithFrame:` but you could define others as needed. Subview layout can be done through constraints, autoresizing masks, or by implementing `layoutSubview`.

Each view controller would instantiate its needed views in the `viewDidLoad`. View layout can be done with constraints, autoresizing masks, or by implementing `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

The use of properties is completely optional. Create public properties for anything to be set/get from an outside class. Optionally create private properties for values internal to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. This does look like an option. However, just like in an answer to a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668221/working-on-custom-component-subclass-uiview-or-uiviewcontroller?rq=1), definition of a UI element is all over the place. Ideally, I would like to use initWithFrame: to only assemble the view by adding various buttons and labels as subViews, and to define those UI elements in separate methods, one for each. So, if you wanted to create a new UIButton and define its type, position, size, image, font, etc. in view.m file, how would you write the method?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Apple website for Sample Code](http://bit.ly/WO1uPz); download everything that you can for applications that are similar to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the link. There's a lot of sample code though.. Any insights on which ones are more relevant to my case, i.e. no IB, subclassing UIView?

Comment: Re-sort the list based on Framework and then look at 'AppKit' entries.  Still a lot of them but focus on 'User Experience' topics.  It is exceptionally common to subclass UIViewControllers and very common to subclass UIViews - should be easy to find something.